# How to save list of objects getting from template in django models?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, save

im using django and i wanna save list of data in my models "Detail_equipement" :

this is my models where i want to save data  :

```
class Detail_equipement(models.Model):

    equipements=models.ForeignKey(Equipement,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=True)
    interventions=models.ForeignKey(Intervention,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    QTE = models.IntegerField()
```

models of foreignkey equipements:

```
class Equipement(models.Model):
    nom_equipement = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    qte_stock=models.IntegerField()
    prix_equipement = models.CharField(max_length=600)
```

and this is my template html when i send data to views  :

```
{%  block content %}

<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 grid-margin stretch-card">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Ajouter Intervention</h4>
                    <form id="modal_form_signup" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
              
                          <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                  <h5 class="modal-title">
                                      <i class="fa fa-lock mr-1"></i>Detail Equipement Utiliser
                                  </h5>
                                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                      <span>&times;</span>
                                  </button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body">
                                  <div class="form-row">
                                    {% for equipment in interv.equipements.all %}
              
                                      <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                          <label for="modal_signup_firstname">Equipement</label>
                                          <div class="input-group">
                                              
                                              <input type="text" id="modal_signup_firstname" name="equipements" value="{{ equipment.nom_equipement }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Equipement" disabled/>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                  
                                            
                                       
                                          
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                              <label for="modal_signup_lastname">QTE</label>
                                              <div class="input-group">
                                                
                                                  <input type="text" id="modal_signup_lastname" name="qte" class="form-control" placeholder="QTE" />
                                              </div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      {% endfor %}
                                  </div>
                                 
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
                                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmer</button>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </form>
            
</div>
</div>
{%  endblock content %}
```

[image]

im trying to use for loop to bring all data but it not working for me it show error

> "GET /techniciens/terminer/7 HTTP/1.1" 200 13999

So Here is my function in views.py :

```
def terminer(request,pk):
        get_interv= Intervention.objects.get(id=pk)
        if request.method=='POST':
            equipements = request.POST.getlist('equipements')
            qte = request.POST.getlist('qte')
            for equip in equipements:
                for qt in qte:
                    d=Detail_equipement(equipements=Equipement.objects.get(id=equipements),interventions=get_interv,QTE=qte)
                    

        
        context = {
                    'interv':get_interv,
                    
                    }
        return render(request, 'techniciens/terminer_interv.html',context)
```

Comment: 200 is not an error code!

Comment: hi ! owkay thanks for your answer but if you can help me ! how can i save list of data to my database models ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using `getlist` instead of just `get` and are sending over simple strings, not lists of items. Based on your form, your view should probably look like this (assuming you have a single field):

```
def terminer(request,pk):
        get_interv= Intervention.objects.get(id=pk)
        if request.method=='POST' and request.is_ajax():
            equipements = request.POST.get('equipements')
            qte = request.POST.get('qte')
            # do something with equipements and qte
```

`getlist` works with form multi-selects and similar objects, like this:

```
    <select name="equipements" id="equipements" multiple>
{% for equipment in interv.equipements.all %} 
        <option value="{{equipment.id}}">{{equipment.nome}}</option>
{% endfor %}
      </select>
```

If you need to collect multiple variables for each entry, you could perhaps do it dynamically via JavaScript:

```
$("#mysubmitbutton").click(function(){
    {% for equipment in interv.equipments.all %}
       var equipment_{{equipment.id}} =  $("#equipment_type_{{equipment.id}}").val();
       var equipment_{{equipment.id}}_qty = $("#equipment_qty_{{equipment.id}}").val();
    {% endfor %}

    var equipments = [
      {% for equipment in interv.equipments.all %}
        { id: equipment_{{equipment.id}}, qty: equipment_{{equipment.id}}_qty,
      {% endfor %}
    ];
    var form_field1 = $("#field1").val();
    var csrfToken = $( "input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']");
//collect the rest of the form here
$.ajax({
    ContentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{% url 'Detail_equipement' %}',
    data: { "equipments": equipments, 'form_field1': form_field1, ..., 'csrdmiddlewaretoken':csrftoken, })
               .done(function(data) {
                            if (data.result === true){
                                alert(data.message);
                           }
                       });
});
```

In your template:

```
 {% for equipment in interv.equipements.all %}
                  
                                          <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                              <label for="modal_signup_firstname">Equipement</label>
                                              <div class="input-group">
                                                  
                                                  <input type="text" id="equipment_type_{{equipment.id}}" name="equipment_type_{{equipment.id}}" value="{{ equipment.nom_equipement }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Equipement" disabled/>
                                              </div>
                                          </div>
</div>
                                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                              <label for="modal_signup_lastname">QTE</label>
                                              <div class="input-group">
                                                
                                                  <input type="text" id="equipment_{{equipment.id}}_qty" name="equipment_{{equipment.id}}_qty" class="form-control" placeholder="QTE" />
                                              </div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Then, in your view you should be able to use `getlist`:

```
def terminer(request,pk):
            get_interv= Intervention.objects.get(id=pk)
            data = {}
            if request.method=='POST' and request.is_ajax():
                equipements = request.POST.getlist('equipments')
                for e in equipements:
                   detail = Detail_equipement.objects.get_or_create(equipements__id=e['id'])
                   detail.QTE = e['qty']
                   detail.save()
             if request.is_ajax():
                return JsonResponse(data)
             else:
                context = {
                'interv':get_interv,
                
                }
                return render(request, 'techniciens/terminer_interv.html',context)
```

Also, `default=True` doesn't do anything in a `ForeignKey` field and you'll need to update your model to this for my code to work (or pass the interventions value in the POST data via ajax):

```
class Detail_equipement(models.Model):

    equipements=models.ForeignKey(Equipement,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    interventions=models.ForeignKey(Intervention,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    QTE = models.IntegerField()
```

This may need some tweaking, as I can't see the rest of your code to be sure it will work. But hopefully it will get you started.

Comment: thank you for your answer but the problem how can i save all data ( mean for each equipements her qte ) in the database ?

Comment: You just get iterate over the equipment list, get the equipment object based on the id, and update and save it

Comment: yeah i appreciate that , but :                                                                                     
 detail = Detail_equipement.objects.get(equipements__id=e['id']) : i didn't have any equipements  yet in my models , that's the point that i'll save it from template wait i'll add screen of my form

Comment: Then use get_or_create (I updated my code to show it, but see my comment below for changes needed for it to work)

Comment: I updated my code to use get_or_create but in order to use my code, you'll either have to pass the Interventions data in the POST data or make Interventions blank=True and null=True in the model

Comment: i see i also updated my post so to better understand , i have a model where i store equipements named "Equipement" so in my template i loop all equipement  with qte field : what i want to do is when i fill qte field and click confirm save to "Detail_equipement" ---> equipement  --->qte .... (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: The code I posted does that but you may have to modify it to work properly in your environment.

Comment: i didn't understand javascript codes , and when i copy past it show an error in {% ... , " Expression expected."

Comment: Without seeing the whole error I can't help. I'm sorry, but what I posted will work but you will have to experiment with it to learn it. There are other ways to do it, but they require a lot more code. You'll have to experiment.

Comment: its okay im lost here :/ , btw thank a lot Michael Hawkins , we can talk on other social media so i can better explain ? pls

Comment: Sure, that is fine. I am glad to help however I can. I believe my email is in my bio here - so feel free to send me a message there.

Comment: Done check your email ;)